# Random chaff insertion in ssh session

Tags: ssh

I am using Mininet to create an SDN environment with multiple hosts. I am establishing SSH sessions between hosts. I want to insert random packets (chaff) into the ssh sessions to mislead network analysis tools.

Comment: You could of course modify client and/or server to insert `SSH2_MSG_IGNORE` packets into the stream. I think the packet type is encrypted, but I am not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to decrease `ClientAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveInterval` to 1 second each. This will produce a constant stream of packets on any idle connection.

When lowering the interval you need to also increase `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ServerAliveCountMax` correspondingly to avoid connections closing too soon in case of packet drops.

Comment: The problem is Mininet uses process-based virtualization where multiple hosts run on the same OS kernel. Modifying these parameters mean all the SSH sessions will be affected. Selectively inserting random packets will not be possible.

Nevertheless, your reply is helpful and has set me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave You can run more than one `sshd` on a single kernel. And `ServerAliveInterval` is a client side setting which you can override for each individual `ssh` command.

Comment: Is there a way for the server to stop responding to the Server Alive messages sent by the client? @kasperd

Comment: @Dave Only if the connection is lost. If you want to send messages in one direction that are simply ignored by the receiving end of the connection, you will have to modify the code to insert `SSH2_MSG_IGNORE` messages in the stream.